# OpenOffice 3.3.0 silent installation through SCCM

Tags: installation, sccm, silent, openoffice

I'm trying to perform a installation of OpenOffice 3.3.0 so that we can distribute it through SMS on our Windows clients.

I found an [article on the OpenOffice wiki](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/Administration_Guide/Windows) on how to perform such installation but it doesn't works for me. The setup stops and nothing happens.

Maybe someone out there has had the same experience and can provide me some help, that would be nice.

Comment: I don't know about SMS installations, but I highly recommend you switch to the [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) fork of the OpenOffice project. Oracle has all but dropped development on their end and development momentum has gathered behind the independent project instead.

Comment: I'm gad you found an answer. Still consider migrating :) Also can you post that as an answer instead of a comment so that future searchers can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which works for OpenOffice 3.3, with the following command you can trigger an unattended installation:

`msiexec SETUP_USED=1 /qn /i openofficeorg33.msi`

It is important to set the SETUP_USED=1 variable other wise you will always get the following error message "Please use the file setup.exe to start the installation".

Bye, Martin